The offset of the data in the column
Help with the problem. There are filled cells A1:A3, there are also filled cells B1:B3. I am adding a value to cell A4 and I need the available data to be in the range B1:B3 shifted down, that is, cell B1 became empty And the values that were in cells B1:B3 moved to cells B2:B4
Before

After

it is worth noting that the cells in the first column are filled with the IMPORTAGE function
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e && e.source) {
    if (e.source.getSheetName() !== 'Calculation') return;
  }
  if (e) {
    if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value != '') {
      var row = e.range.rowStart + 2;
      var column = e.range.columnStart + 1;
      var nextRow = row + 1;
      var nextColumn = column;
      var range = e.range.offset(nextRow, 0);
      if (SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).isBlank()) {
        // Если диапазон пуст, активируем его
        SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).activate();
      } else {
        // Если диапазон не пуст, добавляем сообщение об ошибке
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Ошибка: диапазон не пуст");
      }
    } else if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowStart <= 3) {
      var row = e.range.rowStart + 1;
      var column = e.range.columnStart + 1;
      var nextRow = row + 1;
      var nextColumn = column;
      var range = e.range.offset(nextRow, 0);
      if (SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).isBlank()) {
        // Если диапазон пуст, активируем его
        SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).activate();
      } else {
        // Если диапазон не пуст, добавляем сообщение об ошибке
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Ошибка: диапазон не пуст");
      }
    }
  }
}


"it doesn't work": does anything happen? Are there any errors? What steps have you taken to debug it?

according to the execution history, everything is executed without errors. but the data doesn't move down

What steps have you taken to debug it? Do all your variables contain the expected data? Are all your conditionals executing as you desire?

I'm sorry, but I don't understand javascript. and I don't know how to check the correctness of its execution. in addition, the execution report does not show any error.

initially, my code looked like this function onEdit(e) {
if (e) {
if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value != '') {
var row = e.range.rowStart + 2;
var column = e.range.columnStart + 1;
var nextRow = row + 1;
var nextColumn = column;
var range = e.range.offset(nextRow, 0);
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).isBlank()) {
// Если диапазон пуст, активируем его
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).activate();
}
}
}
}

Start by using console.log() to log the variables and see if they are what you expect them to be.

sorry, I can't find a place to store the log

What do you mean? console.log() displays it in the execution log.

Project without a title
onEdit Trigger Aug. 5 2024, 20:00:41 0.425 sec.
Execution completed
Cloud Console Logs
Aug. 5 2024, 20:00:42 Debugging

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-HnqwwW4IabPSBSyKVCBQ54MXiTOzlaO9_viF4c4YY/edit?usp=sharing

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Follow-up question should not be added as an edit. Instead a follow-up question should be create as you did but you failed to make it clear how that question is different from this one and why the answer provided as not helpful.

Just to remind you, the formula results change will not run an onEdit trigger.
A workaround is to set an installable on-edit trigger on the IMPORTRANGE source spreadsheet instead of the spreadsheet holding the formula.
You should use an installable trigger because a simple trigger can't execute methods that require authorization. In this case, you should use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl or SpreadsheetApp.openById or SpreadsheetApp.open. All of them require authorization to run.

Below is an oversimplified example that works on a spreadsheet that doesn't use IMPORTRANGE
function onEdit(e) {
    const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
    const rangeColB = sheet.getRange(1,2,values.length,1);
    rangeColB.moveTo(sheet.getRange(2,2));
}

The version for the source spreadsheet should be slightly different, as it will use one of the methods mentioned to get the spreadsheet to be modified.
function onEditHandler(e) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(/** put here the spreasheet URL */).getSheetByName(/** put here the sheet name*/);
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
    const rangeColB = sheet.getRange(1,2,values.length,1);
    rangeColB.moveTo(sheet.getRange(2,2));
}


I have given all the necessary permissions for authorization

@ТимАбрамс I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Are you referring to the script bound to the spreadsheet holding the formula or a script bound to the source spreadsheet?

now I'm trying to do it just in one table. without using the IMPORTAGE function. just adding the data to the first column

Please take a look for yourself https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-HnqwwW4IabPSBSyKVCBQ54MXiTOzlaO9_viF4c4YY/edit?usp=sharing

@ТимАбрамс The linked spreadsheet doesn't have a formula using IMPORTRANGE. It looks a very different use case.

I know, I just decided to simplify the task so that it would be easier for me to understand myself. and temporarily do not use the IMPORTAGE function

@ТимАбрамс I added a couple of scripts

wow! It started moving! There is already progress! but the problem is that it shifts with ANY(Delete,ADD data) change in column "A", and I need column "B" to be aligned with the last value in column "A"

Also, when changing in column "B", it also shifts down, this should not happen

@ТимАбрамс I'm glad you're making progress. As I mentioned, the code is oversimplified. It was intended to help you get unstuck. You should extend it to meet your requirements.

I'm very glad that you let me try to do everything myself. unfortunately, this is difficult because my knowledge of javasript is at zero level.

@ТимАбрамс This site is not intended to provide tutorials or code that meet a complete set of requirements. Questions should be about problems that are specific to programming. You should spend some time learning JavaScript, and if you get stuck, please feel free to ask a new question. Please ensure that your future questions are about a specific problem that is unique to programming.

@Wiked OK, I had a hard time writing the code. I had to ask GPT for help. he helped because of this, the code doesn't look very nice, but it works. But it doesn't work exactly the way I wanted it to. could you give me another hint which function to use next?

@ТимАбрамс Follow-up questions should be posted as new question.

@Wiked Sorry I didn't know that, but it would create a lot of unnecessary information.

@ТимАбрамс Don't include unncesary information, just ensure that it's self contained.
